# Taken photo is not saved

Tags: android, python, sl4a

**What device(s) are you experiencing the problem on?**
Sony Ericsson Arc S

**What firmware version are you running on the device?**
Android 4.4.4

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import android

droid = android.Android()
droid.cameraInteractiveCapturePicture('/storage/sdcard0/Download/foo.jpg')
exit()
```

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
Expected:
User take a photo and after click the tick, the photo is saved and can be seen at the specified path`(/storage/sdcard0/Download/)` with the specified name`(foo.jpg)`

**Instead of it:**
After put the tick, the camera quit and the script is running, doesn't reach exit()

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
The newest one: sl4a r6x03
OS: Windows 8.1 Enterprise

**Please provide any additional information below.**
I tried with other pathes(windows Download folder and android sl4's script folder) and emulator(Android virtual device).

**UPDATE**
- The photo is created but cannot be seen on my comuputer file browser, but if I open browser on my phone I see and I can open the created photo(s).
- The "cameraInteractiveCapturePicture" never return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I connect my phone in MTP mode and then some files are not visible for the computer. If I choose UMS I can acces the files but i needed a kitkat widget: running a system wide media scan. Normal apps can't do this anymore as of KitKat so you need root unfortunately. I used this app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.logika.rescan&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can see the same issue [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-scripting/kK6RfC8SVBc). It seems device specific and solved by the self.path = "your path" ;

Comment: I need more code. "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: it seems device specific...(?)

Comment: I updated my problem after some investigation. The photo is created but cannot be seen from my computer.